# findTrees method does not work in Nest JS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I've got a problem using tree entity. I'm using typeORM with nestjs.
My entity is this:

```
@Entity()
@Tree('closure-table')
export class PermissionEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true, unique: true })
  key: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  displayName?: string;

  @TreeChildren()
  children: PermissionEntity[];

  @TreeParent()
  parent: PermissionEntity;
}
```

In my module I added the entity this way :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    RolesModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PermissionEntity]),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'PERMISSION_SERVICE',
      useClass: PermissionsService,
    },
    {
      provide: 'APP_GUARD',
      useClass: JwtAuthGuard,
    },
  ],
  controllers: [PermissionsController],
})
export class PermissionsModule {}
```

The codes below is my service file:

```
export class PermissionsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(PermissionEntity)
    private readonly permissionRepository: TreeRepository<PermissionEntity>,
    @Inject('USER_SERVICE') private readonly userService: UsersService,
    @Inject('ROLES_SERVICE') private readonly rolesService: RolesService,
  ) {}

  async create(registerPermissionDto: RegisterPermissionDto) {
    this.permissionRepository.create(registerPermissionDto);
    return this.permissionRepository.save(registerPermissionDto);
  }

  async getUserPermissions(userId: number, ownerId: number) {
    return this.permissionRepository.findTrees();
  }

}
```

When getUserPermissions() service is called this error occures in console:

> [Nest] 10644  - 08/12/2022, 8:15:44 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] this.permissionRepository.findTrees is not a function

I've searched every where and I could not succeed in finding a solution ! Is there a bug with nestJs and typeORM Tree entity ? Or do we have working example ?

Answer (score 1):

use like this:

first inject this

```
@InjectDataSource() 
private readonly dataSource: DataSource,
```

then:

```
this.dataSource.getTreeRepository(PermissionEntity).findTrees();
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. the "then" part throws a typescript error: `any
Property 'getTreeRepository' does not exist on type 'PermissionEntity'.`PermissionEntity is the dataSource